# What does this SEP contribution language from IRS mean?

Tags: irs, sep-ira

The [IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/how-much-can-i-contribute-to-my-self-employed-sep-plan-if-i-participate-in-my-employers-simple-ira-plan#:%7E:text=SEP%20plan%20limits&text=For%20a%20self%2Demployed%20individual,2021%3B%20%2457%2C000%20for%202020) has the following:

> For a self-employed individual, contributions are limited to 25% of your net earnings from self-employment (not including contributions for yourself), up to $61,000 for 2022 ($58,000 for 2021; $57,000 for 2020)

I do not understand the parenthetic remark "not including contributions for yourself".  To what does it refer? That sentence makes no sense to me.

If I am self-employed, am I my employer?

Comment: If you're self employed then yes, you're your own employer. That's what "self-" means. Not sure what's confusing?

Comment: If I'm self employed, and am my own employer, what I don't understand is that my contributions are limited to 25% of my net earnings *not including contributions for [my]self*. My contributions for myself don't include contributions for myself???

Comment: You can't deduct contributions for yourself from the gross, that's what it means. For other employees your contributions are a deduction from income, but not for yourself.

Comment: When you say "deduct" do you mean "subtract" or "take as a deduction"?

Comment: Taking a deduction leads to substracting the amount, not sure I understand, again...

Comment: I think I understand: I cannot reduce my gross business income with SEP contributions made to my own retirement account.  I'm not trying to figure out what is deductible, but what the maximum contribution allowed would be.  Is the max allowed greater than 25% of my net business income?

Comment: It's the lesser of 25% of your net income or the nominal max amount ($61K for 2022).

Comment: I really don't understand in that case what Turbo Tax is doing in its worksheet for 2023, where it calculates *Contribution dollar limit* as $330,000 multiplied by the "Self-employed reduced rate" (but not to exceed $66,000).  $66,000 is a constant, not the result of any calculation. It calculates *Total maximum allowable deduction* as net earnings multiplied by .20.  So it's making a distinction between how much you can contribute to the SEP and how much you can claim as a deduction.

Comment: @Tim SEP plan can set a contribution rate of less than 20%, so Turbo Tax is just saying that the contribution dollar limit is $330,000 * x% (where x% is the plan's contribution rate) and also limited by $66,000 (which would be where x% = 20%). In the case where a SEP plan's contribution rate is 15%, for example, the contribution limit would be $330,000 * 15% = $49,500.

Comment: @StanH  One of the (many) things that has me confused is the notion that I'm my employer (as a sole proprietor with no other employees) and whether the "plan's contribution rate" refers to what the *employer* contributes and whether the employee can supplement the employer's contribution.  I thought it might be possible for the "business" to contribute to the account and for me personally to contribute to the account, with the total combined contribution being subject to the cap of $66,000.

Comment: @StanH   That seemed reasonable to me to cover situations where, as a sole proprietor, income can vary dramatically year to year, often in a "feast or famine" scenario, so that for one year there may be no money to put in the retirement account and the next year one could play catchup if it happened to be a much better year.

Comment: @Tim SEP plans don't allow for employee deferrals. If you're a sole proprietor with no employees, and if you want to be able to supplement with employee deferrals to reach the $66k easier, you might consider a Solo 401(k) plan if you're eligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contributions for self are limited by the lesser of 25% of your business net income or the nominal max amount ($61,000 for 2022).

In order to reach the net income for your business you calculate all your deductible business expenses and subtract that amount from your gross income. What the quote says is that your contributions for *yourself* should not be included in *that math to reach the net income for the purpose of calculating your contributions* (it would still be included for the purpose of calculating the taxes), but your contributions for your other employees should be (as it is a deductible expense for you).

Comment: Are you certain that the *Contribution dollar limit* (for yourself) cannot be as much as $66,000 even when the *maximum deductible contribution* is less than $66,000?  The Turbo Tax Keogh/SEP worksheet gives those two numbers separately.

Comment: @Tim can't speak for TurboTax, but here's the IRS: https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/sep-contribution-limits-including-grandfathered-sarseps

Comment: Thanks.  I'm finding it all very confusing. I'd like to make a "catch-up contribution" if it's allowed, and if it is allowed, I don't see how to calculate the contribution limit.  I don't think I have the right kind of SEP to do it.

Comment: @Tim unfortunately there's no catch-up contribution provision for SEP plans.